# Need a query to display a grid like given

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Unit Table**

```
Unit    Type    PrimaryCode SecondaryCodes
UnitA   L   20  30,90
UnitB   B   10  25,35,45
```

L – Location ; B – Business;
 If type = L then primary code will be consider as Location and secondary codes as Businesses;

If type = B then primary code will be consider as Business and secondary codes as Locations;

**Accounts Table**

```
Account Location    Business    Amount
AC1 20  30  100
AC2 20  90  50
AC3 25  10  50
AC4 35  10  25
AC5 45  10  100
```

Now, I need a query to display a grid like below..

```
Unit    Sum of Amount
UnitA   150
UnitB   175
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can not at the moment think of anything "nicer".

```
  select 'A' as Unit, sum(Amount) as [Sum of Amount] FROM [Accounts Table] group by Location having count(Location) >1
  union all
  select 'B' as Unit, sum(Amount) as [Sum of Amount] FROM [Accounts Table] group by Business having count(Business) >1
```

**EDIT 1**
I see that I did not consider Unit Table. I'll Fix it.

**EDIT 2**
...Actually, I can not give a better response.
I can not connect these tables - unless the primary code and secondary code form a unique pair.
You'll need a UnitId or UnitName in table [Accounts Table]. Then, this could be group by UnitID.

Comment: No..we don't have the unitname in [Account table]. our Key is Primary and secondary codes

Comment: Well, but see: you probably could have also UnitC, UnitD and so on.
In this case, my answer turns out to be too basic and it will not work correctly. So you must have something unique that will help in joimning Unite with the values ​​20 and  30, 90 Without this we will not be happy when different Unit will have the same Location or Business.

Comment: //different Unit will have the same Location or Business//

Different Units will never have the same combination of Location & Business. The combination must be unique

Comment: In that case, I can see how this link, but unfortunately I'm not so good at sql to write it now as one no-function query. I will come back to the topic in a few days. Maybe someone more experienced will be able to help you more quickly.